# Margin note left of mdframed images in a two column page

Tags: two-column, mdframed, marginpar, marginnote

Is it possible to have a margin note to the left of the left column on the second page with this code and approximately halfway down the page?  I cannot get it to show up using `\marginpar` or the `marginnote` package.  I want the rest of the document to look approximately the same.  I am using the `multicol` package because I don't want the entire document to be two columns just the second page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\geometry{headheight = 0.7in}
\pagestyle{fancy}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[LR]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}}\fancyfoot[LR]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}}}

\fancyhead[C]{\Huge{Lorem Ipsum} \\ \Large{Dolor sit amet}}
\fancyfoot[C]{loremipsum.com \\
\vspace{.1in}
loremipsum@gmail.com \\
\vspace{.1in}
555-555-5555}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black!30,backgroundcolor=black!5]
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\columnbreak

\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `twocolumn` class option and use the `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` switches to change layouts through the document, but that still doesn't fix the fact that a `\marginpar` is not allowed within `mdframed` environments. Is manual positioning of the note acceptable?

Comment: However, `\marginnote` _does_ work inside `mdframed`, so that is a solution. It does affect your manual spacing between the figures though. I can post my work as an answer if you'd like to see what I did.

Comment: Yes please.  I would love to see what you did.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want only this part in two columns, the best choice is the one you've made, in my opinion (use `multicols`).

You have to use `\reversemarginpar` otherwise the margin par will be printed on the right.

Also, adjusting the vertical offset through the second optional argument of `\marginnote` gives the correct positioning.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove demo option in your document
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\geometry{headheight = 0.7in}
\pagestyle{fancy}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[LR]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}}\fancyfoot[LR]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}}}

\fancyhead[C]{\Huge{Lorem Ipsum} \\ \Large{Dolor sit amet}}
\fancyfoot[C]{loremipsum.com \\
\vspace{.1in}
loremipsum@gmail.com \\
\vspace{.1in}
555-555-5555}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black!30,backgroundcolor=black!5]
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\reversemarginpar\marginnote{This is a marginal note}[-\baselineskip]

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\columnbreak

\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

In regards of the vertical offset, it should be a multiple of `\baselineskip`. You should calculate `-0.5\baselineskip` for each line in the margin par.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I used:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo option since I didn't have your placeholder file
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\geometry{headheight = 0.7in,marginparwidth=10ex}% adjusted marginparwidth to fit note
\pagestyle{fancy}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[LR]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}}\fancyfoot[LR]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}}}

\fancyhead[C]{\Huge{Lorem Ipsum} \\ \Large{Dolor sit amet}}
\fancyfoot[C]{loremipsum.com \\
\vspace{.1in}
loremipsum@gmail.com \\
\vspace{.1in}
555-555-5555}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn % put output into one column mode
\lipsum[1]

\newpage\twocolumn % revert to two column for this page

\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black!30,backgroundcolor=black!5]
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}
\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}\reversemarginpar\marginnote{Test.}%

\vspace{.05in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\vspace{.1in}

\includegraphics[height=1.75in, keepaspectratio=true]{placeholder}

\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\vfill\break
\lipsum[1]

%\onecolumn % uncomment after end of twocolumn page to revert to one column for the remainder

\end{document}
```

With output: [image]